# I want to ask whats the diffence between these KO bindings

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I would like to ask whats the difference with these two apply bindings
on my code i change a lot because i use the number 2. please define. thanks.

First

```
 var viewModel = function ()
 {
  ...
  ...
 }

 var VM = new viewModel();

 $(function() {
    ko.applybinding(VM)
 })
```

OR

```
 var viewModel = function ()
 {
  ...
  ...
 }

 $(function() {
    var VM = viewModel();
    ko.applybinding(VM)
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether `viewModel` is implemented as a "classical" constructor that needs to be instantiated with `new` or as a "factory" that explicitly returns an object.

Example of classical constructor:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self=this;
  self.property=ko.observable();
  self.list=ko.observableArray();
}
```

Note that standard JavaScript convention is to start names of classical constructors with a capital letter.

Example of a factory/functional constructor:

```
function viewModel() {
  var self={};
  self.property=ko.observable();
  self.list=ko.observableArray();
  return self;
}
```

In most cases it's just a matter of personal choice which to use. I'd suggest reading the chapters on objects and inheritance in Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* to get a grip on the nuances. Just offhand, the "classical" method is probably better if you're creating inheritance hierarchies or doing lots of run-time type inference with `instanceof`; the "factory" method is probably better if you're using a functional-programming style since you can simply pass the factory as a callback without having to wrap it all the time.